# How do I empty only certain elements from a div wrapper in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Basically my code is

```
<div class='wrapper'>
     <img class='icon'>
     <img class='to be removed'>
     <div class='brkr'></div>
 </div>
```

I want to empty my div of class='wrapper' but I don't want to remove all elements just most.  I have elements of the same name and class outside of this div so I can't just remove all elements of type img.'to be removed' but I also can't use the .empty() function because it doesn't seem to let me specify particular elements.

Any tips or ideas?

Comment: Can you set a class of elements you want to remove?

Comment: Exactly which elements do you want to remove? What does "just most" mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.wrapper').find('.removeClass').remove();
```

Comment: +1 for using `find`. I didn't know it myself for the longest time, but using `find` is far more efficient than multi-level css expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that classes can't have spaces in them. `<img class='to be removed'>` actually sets 3 classes on the img tag.

Change your code to something like `<img class='removeThis'>` and then the below code will work

```
$(".wrapper").find("img.removeThis").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove certain elements inside the `div.wrapper`, then you can use a specific selector, and then `.remove()`:

```
$("div.wrapper .to-remove").remove();
```

This only removes the `.to-remove` elements inside `div.wrapper`, and not other elements inside or outside the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting purely by id select by $('#divid #elementid') or classes, or whatever you want to select by.  Either way you just need a multiple level select.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.wrapper img[class="to be removed"]').remove()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rCEEt/